# get the value from hash map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a Rack Request hash from `request` as given below

```
# < Rack::Request: 0x0000565215613880
@params = {
    "utf8" => "✓",
    "authenticity_token" => "FcL/+sUVBdR7LePfLG2WMOsJRWuVvg=="
  },

  @env = {
           ---
           ---
           ---
           @delegate = {
              "_csrf_token" => "+wgvuiHZm6QNvJjUaIpiYU=",
              "omniauth.params" => {},
              "omniauth.origin" => 
              "https://localhost:3000/users/auth/autologin?abc=xyz",
              "omniauth.state" => "0720b81a9a17dbdgndgn1768fa19a659584b819960"
    },
}>
```

Can someone please help me to get the value of `omniauth.origin` ?
I tried `request.env["omniauth.origin"]` but looks like it is not right way to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try

```
request.env['rack.session']['omniauth.origin']
```

Comment: Thank you @spickermann.. I have tried that one.. but the delegate is within `env`

Comment: It can't be directly in the `env` because `env` is a hash. Is it possible that it is an attribute of another object that is stored in the `env`?

Comment: Yes thats correct its under `request.env["rack.session"]`

Comment: But in what object and what is the key of that object?

Comment: I tried like this.. `request.env['rack.session']['omniauth.origin'] ` It worked.. Thank you @spickermann

Comment: I am glad that my questions pointed you into the right direction. I updated my answer to help future readers. Otherwise, I would have deleted it and then others with a similar question would not even have the chance to see your comment.